# Input capacitor / Inrush current

Tags: capacitor, brushless-dc-motor, current-limiting, inrush-current

I am developing an electronic control board for a brushless motor. The motor in question is part number FR_2057_B_FMM from FAULHABER. The motor is powered at 24V and 62.5W.

For the three-phase inverter, I'm using SiR120DP MOSFETs and MIC4605 gate controllers. This gate drive reference has an output current of 1A. The motor will be controlled with a 20KHz PWM signal.

My board also includes several integrated circuits, such as a micronrontrolleur, temperature sensors, a CAN controller and auxiliary power supplies.

My question is as follows: I'd like to size the input capacitors that will limit the voltage drop when the board starts up and during motor control. What would be the formula for the capacitor value?

In addition, I wanted to know how I could calculate the capacitor inrush current?  And, if necessary, how to integrate a circuit to limit this inrush current.

thank you for any information.

Comment: Limiting inrush current has a number of solutions. I would normally use (for a fairly hefty current) a hotswap controller.

Answer (score 1):

I used this circuit fragment in a similar 24 V application with 5 Motors and a total peak power consumption of 220 W.

[image: Inrush Limiter]

IC 12 is the load switch to turn on the machine. The external power switch contains a LED with resistor. This LED is dimmed while the machine is off via R45 and bright via D13 if the machine in on.

The internal supply +24A rises quickly and the bulk capacitors C04 and C05 are charged via R69. After a delay of about 3 seconds the MCU enables the bypass MOSFET T15 via GPIO24 to directly connect the bulk capacitors to the supply. Motor activity is then enabled.

The MCU watches the supply voltage and disables the bypass if +24A falls below 20 V and reenables this after the supply has returned. This avoids inrush currents after short external supply dropouts.